# Amazon MWS Scratchpad API

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-mws

I am trying to get Amazon MWS Scratchpad working, but it keeps giving me a message:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

I was looking for similar topic out here, but nothing really helpful. So, here is code:

```
$params = array(
    'AWSAccessKeyId'   => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    'Action'           => "GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN",
    'SellerId'         => MERCHANT_ID,
    'SignatureMethod'  => "HmacSHA256",
    'SignatureVersion' => "2",
    'Timestamp'        => gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", time()),
    'Version'          => "2011-10-01",
    'MarketplaceId'    => MARKETPLACE_ID,
    'ItemCondition'    => "new",
    'ASINList.ASIN.1'  => "B001T6OP32");

$url = array();

foreach($params as $key => $val){   
    $val   = str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($val));
    $url[] = $key . '=' . $val;     
}

$uri = implode('&', $url);

$string_to_sign  = 'POST';
$string_to_sign .= "\n";
$string_to_sign .= 'mws.amazonservices.co.uk' . "\n";
$string_to_sign .= '/Products/2011-10-01' . "\n";
$string_to_sign .= $uri;

$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, TRUE);
$signature = base64_encode($signature);
$signature = urlencode($signature);
$signature = str_replace("%7E", "~", $signature);

$url  = 'https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/';
$url .= 'Products/2011-10-01' . '?' . $uri . "&Signature=" . $signature;
```

I bet that problem is with Signature, when I'm printing it with `print $signature` it always contains `%` symbols, and when I'm comparing with [Amazon Scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/scratchpad/index.html) Request Details page, `SHA 256 HMAC` field - there is none.

Maby there is something I can't see? I was checking for spaces in Secret Access Key, it's looks okay.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Just a heads up for when you move past the signature portion. The scratch pad won't help you at all when you start testing your xml. You can type anything you want into the xml section of the scratch pad and it will tell you it is valid and give you a "200" response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working version:

```
$param = array();
$param['AWSAccessKeyId']   = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID; 
$param['Action']           = 'GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN'; 
$param['SellerId']         = MERCHANT_ID; 
$param['SignatureMethod']  = 'HmacSHA256'; 
$param['SignatureVersion'] = '2'; 
$param['Timestamp']        = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
$param['Version']          = '2011-10-01'; 
$param['MarketplaceId']    = MARKETPLACE_ID; 
$param['ItemCondition']    = 'new';
$param['ASINList.ASIN.1']  = << ITEM ASIN >>;

$url = array();
foreach ($param as $key => $val) {

    $key = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($key));
    $val = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($val));

    $url[] = "{$key}={$val}";
}

sort($url);

$arr   = implode('&', $url);

$sign  = 'GET' . "\n";
$sign .= 'mws.amazonservices.co.uk' . "\n";
$sign .= '/Products/2011-10-01' . "\n";
$sign .= $arr;

$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $sign, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, true);
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

$link  = "https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/Products/2011-10-01?";
$link .= $arr . "&Signature=" . $signature;
```

Load `$link` with curl and vualia!

Comment: Appreciate for sharing solution which can help others! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

To begin accessing Amazon MWS from PHP, you can download the client library for the Amazon MWS API that you are interested in using, such as the [Products API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/php.html) that you referenced.

Choose an example from the `src/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Samples` directory, fill in your unique values, and run it.

The examples implement authentication using the `MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client` class in `src/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Client.php` which demonstrates how to successfully sign a request.