# Authenticate to Amazon AMS API using PHP POST

Tags: php, api, amazon-mws

I took this code from [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352916/amazon-com-mws-integration) on SO. It works just as advertised. However, I'm trying to do the same thing with `POST` instead of `GET` which is apparently what AMS recommends and is how this particular call is placed on the AMS Scratchpad.

The code that does work with `GET`

```
<?php
$param = array();
$param['AWSAccessKeyId']   = 'YourAccessKeyID'; 
$param['Action']           = 'GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN'; 
$param['SellerId']         = 'YourSellerID'; 
$param['SignatureMethod']  = 'HmacSHA256';  
$param['SignatureVersion'] = '2'; 
$param['Timestamp']        = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
$param['Version']          = '2011-10-01'; 
$param['MarketplaceId']    = 'YourMarketplaceID'; 
$param['ItemCondition']    = 'new';
$param['ASINList.ASIN.1']  = 'B00C5XBAOA';
$secret = 'YourSecretKey';

$url = array();
foreach ($param as $key => $val) {

    $key = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($key));
    $val = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($val));
    $url[] = "{$key}={$val}";
}

sort($url);

$arr   = implode('&', $url);

$sign  = 'GET' . "\n";
$sign .= 'mws.amazonservices.com' . "\n";
$sign .= '/Products/2011-10-01' . "\n";
$sign .= $arr;

$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $sign, $secret, true);
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

$link  = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01?";
$link .= $arr . "&Signature=" . $signature;
echo($link); //for debugging - you can paste this into a browser and see if it loads.

$ch = curl_init($link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo('<p>' . $response . '</p>');
print_r('<p>' . $info . '</p>');
?>
```

The code that does not work with `POST`

```
<?php
$post = '';
$param = array();
$param['AWSAccessKeyId']   = 'YourAccessKeyID'; 
$param['Action']           = 'GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN'; 
$param['SellerId']         = 'YourSellerID'; 
$param['SignatureMethod']  = 'HmacSHA256';  
$param['SignatureVersion'] = '2'; 
$param['Timestamp']        = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
$param['Version']          = '2011-10-01'; 
$param['MarketplaceId']    = 'YourMarketplaceID'; 
$param['ItemCondition']    = 'new';
$param['ASINList.ASIN.1']  = 'B00C5XBAOA';
$secret = 'YourSecretKey';

$url = array();
foreach ($param as $key => $val) {

    $key = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($key));
    $val = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($val));
    $url[] = "{$key}={$val}";
}

sort($url);

$arr   = implode('&', $url);

$sign  = 'POST' . "\n";
$sign .= 'mws.amazonservices.com' . "\n";
$sign .= '/Products/2011-10-01' . "\n";
$sign .= $arr;

$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $sign, $secret, true);
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));
$post .= $arr . "&Signature=" . $signature;
echo $post;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '$post');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = simplexml_load_string($response);
print_r($response);
//print_r($info);

?>
```

I get the following response:

```
(
    [Error] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Type] => Sender
            [Code] => InvalidParameterValue
            [Message] => Either Action or Operation query parameter must be present.
        )

    [RequestID] => b6d5ee02-6ace-4482-92b7-xxxxxxxxxx
)
```

I believe I'm doing something wrong with the signature authentication. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Are you working on api for Amazon marketing services(AMS) ? I need some guidance in getting campaigns and other data via apis for AMS.Please look at below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493037/how-to-get-amazon-marketing-services-ams-sponsored-campaign-programmatically 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the POST script.

You must delete CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER in curl options and delete que single quote on $post on CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://mws.amazonservices.es/Products/2011-10-01");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
echo($response);
```

Salut,
Josep M

Comment: Hi, Are you working on api for Amazon marketing services(AMS) ? I need some guidance in getting campaigns and other data via apis for AMS.Please look at below link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493037/how-to-get-amazon-marketing-services-ams-sponsored-campaign-programmatically Thanks in advance.