# How to get Amazon marketing services (AMS) sponsored campaign programmatically?

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

Greetings!!

**The goal is to get Amazon Marketing service(AMS) sponsored product campaigns through Sponsored products API(If possible)**.

And please suggest if there is any different set of apis for AMS sponsored campaigns.

I have follow all the instruction given on this site.

**https://advertising.amazon.com/API**

I have follow all the instruction given in the guidelines but with that I am not getting campaigns for AMS sponsored product.

> currently I am using "scope:cpc_advertising:campaign_management" to
>   get campaigns but with that I am not getting campaigns for AMS.

Do I pass different scope to get AMS campaigns? And if yes what should be the parameters?

Is that any way to get AMS sponsored products campaigns?

PS : I am using login details of AMS account only. And I am also aware with sponsored products and AMS sponsored products.

Could you please help me to get some information for AMS sponsored campaigns?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Hi James, where you able move forward? if yes what was the issue? How did you get the fix. We too have same issue. We have valid ams account and when login with Amazon we don't get any profiles.

Comment: Hi @Praveena: No, we didn't able to connect AMS account. We are still finding ways to connect it.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading campaigns report using curl call is here.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v1/campaigns/report \
  -H 'Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope: REPLACE_YOUR_PROFILE_ID' \
  -H 'Authorization: REPLACE_YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: advertising-api.amazon.com' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
 "campaignType": "sponsoredProducts",
 "reportDate": "20181205"
 }'
```

Hope this helps to download.

Comment: I think you have misunderstand my issue. My real issue is how to authenticate with AMS? I already have access to advertising api and it's all endpoints including report.